# In Python, how do you read in the date (dd/mm/yyyy) from a list and change it to just the name of the month?

Tags: python, datetime

```
 ['Time Period >>', '2/23/2015', '3/2/2015', '3/9/2015', '3/16/2015', '3/23/2015', '3/30/2015', '4/6/2015', '4/13/2015']
```

How do you take this list and read in the dates and change them to say just the month written out, for example, 2/23/2015 to read February or 3/2/2015 to read March?

The dates constantly change so I was thinking just reading in the first number and making an `if` statement to change it to the month corresponding with the number.

Comment: Consider using: calendar.month_name[number]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to convert your strings into datetime objects. Then we'll convert those back to strings showing just the month using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

This is easier than building a dictionary of month/numeral combinations. It does require all of your date strings to have the same format though. My assumption for this is that it is `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
import datetime
for d in s[1:]:
    try:
        print datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%B")
    except ValueError:
        # Not a datetime string in the expected format...do something else, or ignore 

February
March
March
March
March
March
April
April
```

Here you can see that I am looping through your list of strings, but ignoring the first value (because it's not a date in your example). Each is converted into a datetime then back to just the month, displayed as a string.

Comment: Hello Andy, Thanks for the swift reply. My only thing that I am lastly having trouble with is that sometimes the list has more dates which would not affect anything but at the end of the list is a string 'Total' which is causing an error and that value will change spots depending on how many dates are there. Is there a way to ignore that last string value 'Total'? @Andy

Comment: `for d in s[1:len(s)-1]:`  That will loop through list, starting with the second element (skipping "Time Period") and ending with the second to last element (skipping your 'Total'). Alternatively, you can `try/except` around your conversion and catch the `ValueError`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `datetime` module to do that.

Example -

```
import datetime
datestring = '2/23/2015'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring ,'%m/%d/%Y')
d.strftime('%B')
>>> 'February'
```

Or one line -

```
import datetime
datestring = '2/23/2015'
datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring ,'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%B')
>>> 'February'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is have a dictionary where the `keys` are the month number and the `values` are the month name. Iterate through each item, and split the string at `/`, then get the first element, which is the month number. Then reference the dictionary with the month number to get its corresponding name.

```
monthDictionary = {'1': 'January', '2': 'February', '3': 'March', '4': 'April', '5': 'May',
                   '6': 'June', '7': 'July', '8': 'August', '9':'September', '10':'October',
                   '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}

l = ['Time Period >>', '2/23/2015', '3/2/2015', '3/9/2015', '3/16/2015', '3/23/2015', '3/30/2015', '4/6/2015', '4/13/2015']

for d in l[1:]:
    monthNum = d.split('/')[0]
    print monthDictionary[monthNum]
```

Comment: Nice answer as it explains how to iterate over the list. `for item in l[1:]` would also work, instead of the `range(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your input is valid then you could use a more efficient code (if you need it):

```
In [1]: import calendar

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: dates = ['2/23/2015', '3/2/2015', '3/9/2015', '3/16/2015', '3/23/2015', '3/30/2015', '4/6/2015', '4/13/2015']

In [4]: %timeit [datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime('%B') for s in dates]                          
The slowest run took 1373.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit [calendar.month_name[int(s.partition('/')[0], 10)] for s in dates]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.3 µs per loop
```

`calendar.month_name[int(s.partition('/')[0], 10)]` is noticeably faster here.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply create a function then iterate over the list and call the function passing the date in.

```
def dateToMonth(date):
     months = {1:"Jan", 2:"Feb", 3:"Mar"}
     month = date.split("/")[0]

     return months[int(month)]
```

What this function does is take in your string date, split that into an array based on the locations of the '/' characters.

Then it looks up in the dictionary the "02" converted into an int which comes back as months[2] and returns "Feb"

Comment: Why a dictionary? If the keys are consecutive integers, just use a list. Adjust the number to account for zero-based index.

Comment: if you're going to convert strings like "09" to ints, you'll need to pass the base argument `int(month, 10)`.  But why do all this when the std lib has the `calendar` and `datetime` modules?

Comment: there are multiple ways to skin a cat.  My way I don't need to account for zero indexing though.  Your way also works.

Comment: @JeffH. Agreed. Your way is nice and readable. I suppose I just shy away from a dictionary here automatically because there are other situations where it would make more of a difference. On my system a list `["Jan", "Feb", ...]` takes up 84 bytes, whereas the dictionary `{1:"Jan",2:"Feb", ...} ` takes 436. Not a problem here, with only 12 items, but with larger datasets it might be an important consideration. Accessing the list should also be (slightly) quicker than the dictionary lookup, as Python implements lists using arrays. Again, far more relevant for larger numbers of items.

Comment: If you're going to use a dict, why not skip the conversion to int (and use `{"01": "Jan", "02": "Feb", ...}`

Comment: @Sam you guys are absolutely right, your ways are better.  I just saw a trivial question and gave a trivial answer that worked.  

I didn't bother with memory sizes because a list of months is a pretty constant size, but as you said with bigger datasets, my solution would not be ideal.